# Handling errors in socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a piece of code that looks like this to create an error.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('makeerror', function(data) {
    "asdasd".fun();
  });
});
```

I tried to add

```
socket.on("error", function() {});
// and 
io.sockets.on("error", function() {});
```

But all errors are thrown anyway. After looking at the documentation I couldn't find a way to handle unexpected exceptions. It will make nodejs crash. The reason why I'm asking this is that I'd like to add support for a monitoring solution. If I could handle errors and report them, I'd be very happy to know how to do that. Now, it just crashes.

Comment: Don't do that. See the warnings at  http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

Comment: What am I not supposed to do?

Comment: Don't continue after errors.

Comment: You mean I'd rather have my server crash without knowing what happened?

Comment: If you just want to log, see that link.

Comment: I don't want to log, I want to report the error to a main server that will then notify me when something happens. I just can't have it crash without knowing about it. Even if one error happen, it can be isolated and won't affect every users, it can be tested more easily if I don't have to restart the server. I'm looking for a solution that is less hard than "uncaughtexception". If possible.